# Can't find fingerprint enrollment option on 18.10

Tags: hp, 18.10, fingerprint-reader

My fingerprint sensor is detected on my HP Elitebook 840 G2

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
```

yet I do not have the option under my user account to enable fingerprint. Searching for fingerprint points me to user settings without the prompt.

Comment: Keep in mind that even though the system detects the fingerprint reader, it might not yet be *supported* by the fingerprint systems.  (This is the case on my Dell XPS, and has been reported in the case of many others, about 'size of fingerprint image' not yet being supported by the underlying software libraries for fingerprint recognition)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a Lenovo thinkpad X280. But I think is not a solution for my device right now (06cb:009a).

### [image]

In your case I have read that is a solution if you install the package  **fingerprint-gui**.

Url: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui

I hope this information helps you.